# Making scriptlets invalid in JSPs

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, web.xml, scriptlet

I am trying to make scriptlets invalid by writing the below code in my Deployment descriptor
but still the scriptlets are getting executed.

```
<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>

            <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

Comment: the scriptlets are still executing as they are cached...clear your tomcat cache and restart tomcat..

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure it the other way round.

```
<scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
<el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
```

When the `<scripting-invalid>` is set to `true`, then the container will throw an exception when *scriptlets* (those `<% %>`, `<%= %>` and `<%! %>` things) are still used.

You definitely don't want to set `<el-ignored>` to `true`, otherwise you won't be able to use expression language (those `${}` things), which is the recommended way of accessing the model and executing functions in JSPs. If you disable it as well, then all your JSPs would be useless and can be plain static HTML files as good.

Answer (score 0):

I think the jsp's are already converted to Java servlets. Try regenerating the jsp to servlets.

Comment: Jsp's will only be converted into java servlets when jsp's will be called by someone..